# MVC3 Site.css overriding my custom styles

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this HTML which is generated by MVC3 Razor Engine:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <div id="autoComplete">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.group_name, new { ID = "group_name" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.group_name)
    </div>
</div>
```

And my custom CSS I am writing for my autocomplete functionality:

```
#group_name input[type='text'], input[type='password']
{
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#group_name input[type='text'], input[type='password'] ul
{
    width: 100%;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#group_name input[type='text'], input[type='password'] li
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: default;
    display: block; /*  if width will be 100% horizontal scrollbar will apear     when scroll mode will be used */ /*width: 100%;*/
    font: menu;
    font-size: 12px; /*     it is very important, if line-height not setted or setted   in relative units scroll will be broken in firefox  */
    line-height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it is being overrided by the site.css which comes by default with MVC 3 solution which is this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Does anyone know what CSS I have to write to target my div and input html? Thanks.

Comment: Is your CSS called after or before the site CSS? It would be better if it was afterwards. Also you should specify your css more clearly e.g. "div.mydividorclass input"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using firebug to look at the HTML as it changes. IE has its own javascript debugging options but being able to see the li render in real time and looking at its tag helped me write my css.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

You will need to make your rules more specific to override the site.css styles.

Alternatively, just override your site.css styles in the file itself. Site.css isn't like a library of styles which shouldn't be overriden. It's just a start template which you can edit/delete.